# Oracle join of two tables where joined to table returns highest of a result set restricted by the joining (parent?) table?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Sorry for the long title, but its a difficult dilemma to distill down to a short title..  :-)

I have two tables, an auto maintenance log table and an auto trip log table, something like the following:

auto_maint_log:

- auto_id
- maint_datetime
- maint_description

auto_trip_log:

- auto_id
- trip_datetime
- ending_odometer

I need to select all maintenance events for each auto, and for each event, lookup the most recent ending_odometer value at the time of the maintenance from the trip log table.  The only way I have successfully accomplished this task is using a function (i.e. get_odometer(auto_id, maint_datetime) as a column in my query) in which the odometer reading from the trip log is evaluated to pull the most recent trip prior to the passed maint_datetime, thus returning the most recent ending_odometer.

While the function call does work, in theory, in practice it does not.  My end goal is to create a view of the maintenance data that includes the (then) current odometer value, and I have millions of maintenance rows across hundreds of vehicles.  The performance of the function call makes its use as a solution impractical, nay impossible..  :-)

I've tried all variations of MAX, rownum, subselects, analytics (over/partition, etc.) I've been able to scour from google'ing this, and have not been able to code a working query.

Any suggestions, or brilliant solutions are welcome!

Thanks,

Comment: Gordon provided a great solution below with a correlated subquery, but I failed to mention in my original post that the validity of the odometer data is always in question, so I have to rely on the most recent entry vs. simply the max() of the past values.  My apologies for omitting that detail.  (I tried to mark your answer as useful, but I am apparently to newbie to do that..)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a correlated subquery:

```
select aml.*,
       (select max(atl.ending_odometer)
        from auto_trip_log atl
        where alt.auto_id = aml.auto_id and
              atl.trip_datetime <= aml.maint_datetime
       ) as ending_odometer
from auto_maint_log aml;
```

This query uses `max()` because (presumably) the odometer readings are steadily increasing.

EDIT:

```
select aml.*,
       (select max(atl.ending_odometer) over (dense_rank first order by atl.trip_datetime desc)
        from auto_trip_log atl
        where alt.auto_id = aml.auto_id and
              atl.trip_datetime <= aml.maint_datetime
       ) as ending_odometer
from auto_maint_log aml;
```

Comment: I wish the presumption was true, but unfortunately the odometer entries are at times entered erroneously, hence the reliance on the most recent trip vs. the max() of all previous.

Comment: @SuperDave . . . That was just a simplifying assumption.  You can still do this with a `keep` clause.

Comment: The second query may return more than one row.